# Codeblocks not stopping at all breakpoints

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, codeblocks

I am attempting to build a custom lookup in exim, I have followed the docs and good the groundwork in place so my additional code is being compiled and hooked in, as well as being called.  I am using the Makefile included with Exim to perform the build and I have added in `CFLAGS=-g -O0` to ensure I have debugging symbols.

Codeblocks, gcc, gdb and the source all live on my Linux box, which I am SSHing into and exporting the X session to my Windows desktop using XMing, I don't think this has any baring on the problem, but worth mentioning.

Now, my problem is that when I run debugger with breakpoints in, C::B seems to be not setting or gdb is ignoring breakpoints in my code, but is hitting ones I have in the `main` function (I added one at exit so I could read the execution output and to prove they were working).

I have confirmed my code is actually being called, it currently spits out an error message, which it is doing.  If I add a breakpoint on that line, it doesn't fire, nor if it's on the function or first line of the function.

What is even stranger (to me), is that previously it was working!  it only stopped working when I resized the bottom C::B pane which caused a portion of the screen to not render (I think this is a problem with C::B and XMing, sometimes I just get a grey blank window and need to stop and restart C::B).  So I quit C::B, restarted it, reloaded my project and since then break points in my code simply do not work, even though I can prove the code is being executed.

Also if I manually add the breakpoint it works as expected.  I set a breakpoint in C::B at the start of main.  Hit debug and then sent `b mddfind_open` (name of my function) into gdb and hit continue.. C::B stops again at the start of that function.  Possibly some weirdness with how C::B is passing the breakpoints to gdb?

UPDATE:
The project I am working on is Exim, which links the code into the build directory (due to some bug with gcc 2.92.x and extern's IIRC).  If I open the file from that location in C::B and set a breakpoint it works as expected.  I suspect that C::B is possibly passing incorrect references to gdb?

Any ideas?

Comment: So it is codeblocks problem

Comment: I think it may be that in this case the way the binary is built there is no path information stored with the symbols.  So gdb is looking in the wrong place for the source.  Adding the subpath into the source dirs fixed it.  Thanks

Comment: It does not have anything common with the programming. It is a configuration problem. I am voting to CLOSE

Comment: Reading through the Makefiles, the various components are built into static libraries and then linked into the main executable.  Symbols therefore I would assume would only include file information relative to the static library (which is built in the same location as the source).

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that in this situation I need to specify the source path for the source file in question, even though it is within the root source path.

Originally I had my GDB source path set to:

```
/home/graeme/exim/src
```

The code in question lives in `src/lookups`, so adding that path too fixes the problem

```
/home/graeme/exim/src
/home/graeme/exim/src/lookups
```

I believe this situation has arisen as the code I am building is initially compiled into a static library, this library is then linked into the main program itself.  As such symbols reference the source for the library source files located at the point the library was compiled.  So in this case there are multiple packages being built, and I needed to reference each of them in the source paths.